# How can I adjust the true positive rate (TPR) against the false positive rate (FPR) in a random forest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

Suppose I'm use a random forest binary classifier in R.

What parameter(s) can I tweak in my learned model (or model to be learned) that can help me with this tradeoff.

for example: In logistic regression I would change the threshold on the probability the classifier predicts.

How do I so something similar with randomforest, especially using the R package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the cutoff parameter? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf (predict.randomForest)

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370670/roc-curve-for-classification-from-randomforest has an example.